# The page you requested was not found in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

When I load the view `user/propertie_key/key_propertie_list` returns error 404

And this is my Controller

```
class Key_propertie extends UR_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("user/key_propertie_model", "key_propertie_model");
        $this->load->library('datatable');
}

public function index(){

    $lista = $this->key_propertie_model->getKey();
    $dados = array("ci_broker_propertie_key" => $lista);

    $dados['view'] = 'user/propertie_key/key_propertie_list';
        $this->load->view('layout', $dados);
}
```

This is the error that returns me on the console.

[image]

And here is the full view path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to load the viewfile layout.php, which is not in your directory, hence the error

the correct approach is:

```
public function index(){
    $lista = $this->key_propertie_model->getKey();
    $dados = array("ci_broker_propertie_key" => $lista);
    $this->load->view('user/propertie_key/key_propertie_list', $dados);
}
```

Comment: The strange thing is that I have another view, with the same controller, model and not this error. Of course, the data is from another function, but the logic is the same.

Comment: I was just looking into this again: `$this->load->view('layout')`will load layout.php from your views folder, if it doesn't exist you should get the error `Unable to load the requested file: layout.php` but your error says `the page you requested was not found`, which actually indicates that a controller or model file was not found. Now you need to find out where, use `print_r($an_array_you_want_to_check);die;` to see if you get a valid result from model or later from controller

Answer (score 0):

please try to like this example, hope so work for you

```
public function index(){
         $data =array();
        $data['lista'] = $this->key_propertie_model->getKey();
        $data['view'] = 'load here your view page directory';
        $this->load->view('load layouts here', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with `user/propertie_key` on the URL.